# The select_one() method is not working for a particular URL

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to parse few URLs to scrape the article text from them and the select_one method is working fine for them but not for a particular URL

> URLs:
> 37,https://insights.blackcoffer.com/ai-in-healthcare-to-improve-patient-outcomes/
> 38,https://insights.blackcoffer.com/what-if-the-creation-is-taking-over-the-creator/
> 39,https://insights.blackcoffer.com/what-jobs-will-robots-take-from-humans-in-the-future/
> 40,https://insights.blackcoffer.com/will-machine-replace-the-human-in-the-future-of-work/
> 84,https://insights.blackcoffer.com/how-small-business-can-survive-the-coronavirus-crisis/

The select_one function is not scrapping the article text for the last URL (84)

```
        div_element = article.select_one(
            '.td-post-content.tagdiv-type,.tdb_single_content .tdb-block-inner.td-fix-index')
        print(div_element.text)
```

How do i make it work for the last URL?

I have tried changing the class names and modify them, yet my code is still not able to scrape the article text from the last URL.

This is the entire code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests




source = requests.get(
        'https://insights.blackcoffer.com/ai-in-healthcare-to-improve-patient-outcomes/').text

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
article = soup.find('article')
title = article.find('h1', class_='tdb-title-text').text
div_element = article.select_one(
     '.td-post-content.tagdiv-type,.tdb_single_content .tdb-block-inner.td-fix-index').text
```

Comment: What kind of object is `article`?  Can you show us how it was created

Comment: article = soup.find('article')

Comment: @JohnGordon I have mentioned the entire code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to adjust the CSS selectors. It seems that every page uses a little bit different CSS classes:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://insights.blackcoffer.com/how-small-business-can-survive-the-coronavirus-crisis/'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

article = soup.find('article')

title = article.h1.text
text = article.select_one('.td-post-content').text

print(title)
print(text[:200])
```

Prints:

```
How Small Business can survive the Coronavirus Crisis

The word pandemic may be the most used word for the last decade, and we know why. The year 2020 comes with a lot of unprecedented threats to humans as well as to nature. While no business was left in
```

Comment: This works but i want i want to keep the class ".tdb_single_content .tdb-block-inner.td-fix-index" inside my method too.

Comment: @StudywithMe You can use for example `.select_one('.td-post-content, .tdb_single_content .tdb-block-inner.td-fix-index')`